# How to approximate the radius of a circle containing a group of circles?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, geometry, circle-pack

In my program I have an array of circles, each with an `x`, `y`, and `r` component. The `r` (radius) is `10` for all of them, and there can be anywhere between 1 and 1000 circles contained within the list.

They are all clumped around each other, such that they look like this:

[image]

My question is, what is a good way to approximate the radius of the outer circle? It does not need to be very accurate at all, and I am mostly looking for a very fast way to calculate this.

My current solution is basically this:

`const outerRadius = (10 * innerCount) / 2`

which is not very accurate, so I am looking for something more accurate, but ideally still `O(1)`.

Comment: it looks like 3 diameters, or 6*r, if r is supposed to be the radius of the inner circles.

Comment: Are there always 7 circles in your array? If so, I think @PresidentJamesK.Polk has it right.

Comment: @mykaf No there can be an arbitrary amount of circles. So there could be anywhere between 1 and 1000 circles contained within

Comment: Are the circles in your array all the same size?

Comment: Yes all circles in the array are the same size

Comment: I'd probably use the sum of the areas of the inner circle to approximate the area of the large circle, then determine radius from there. The more circles in your array, the more accurate the result.

Comment: @mykaf posted an answer based on your comments

Comment: The geometry here needs more explaining. For example, is the outer circle radius fixed and then a number of smaller inner circles fitted inside, or is there some other rule for how inner circles are packed into the outer circle? For example, if there must always be at least one outer circle diameter where an integral number of inner circle diameters must fit exactly then that constrains the possible values of the radius of the outer circle, such that perhaps that radius can be computed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

@mykaf, is something like this what you had in mind? Wrote it based on your comments, but not sure if there's a better way:

```
function calculateOuterRadius(innerCircleCount, innerCircleRadius) {
  const factor = 1.33;
  const area = Math.PI * innerCircleRadius * innerCircleRadius * innerCircleCount * factor;

  return Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
}
```

An even better way, since `Math.PI` cancels out:

```
function calculateOuterRadius2(innerCircleCount, innerCircleRadius) {
  return Math.sqrt(innerCircleCount * innerCircleRadius * innerCircleRadius);
}
```

Which I think can be further reduced to this?

```
function calculateOuterRadius3(innerCircleCount, innerCircleRadius) {
  return Math.sqrt(innerCircleCount) * innerCircleRadius;
}
```

Comment: What does `factor` represent?

Comment: If I did my math right, I believe R (radius of large circle) should be roughly equal to the square root of the sums of the squares of the individual circles. `R = Math.sqrt(innerCircleCount*r*r)` You multiply by `Math.PI` to calculate area, then use `area/Math.PI` in your result - so `Math.PI` cancels itself out.

Comment: Oh, you're correct! I'll update my answer

Comment: With two inner circles which is the worst case error, this gives `√2 * innerRadius`, while the exact value is `2 * innerRadius`. The error term improves with more inner circles.  It might be worthwhile it to code a special case for `innerCircleCount === 2`

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement on the OP's answer for two adjacent inner circles, where the approximation error is most extreme...

```
// count and radius refer to innerCircleCount and innerCircleRadius
function calculateOuterRadius(count, radius) {
  return count === 2 ? 2 * radius : Math.sqrt(count) * radius;
}
```